# Is there such a thing as a window which is drawn to a bitmap rather than to the display surface?

Tags: windows, api, gdi

Is there anyway to create a HWND that is drawn onto a bitmap (acting as a virtual display surface) rather than onto the actual display surface?

It would seem such a thing would be useful because there are things you can do with a window you can not do with a DC such as creating child windows (perhaps containing controls) or getting DC via GetDCEx.

Comment: not perfecly clear what you want, a window with a background image?

Comment: The problem with a window backed by the display is that has to be non-minimized and entirely visible b4 you can do things to it.  I'm looking for some way to avoid those difficulties and generate bitmaps with images of controls that I can use for non-display purposes. For example put a control on the screen, reposition the control so that it is off the screen then try to capture the controls image.

Comment: Meant to say For example put a control on the screen, reposition the WINDOW so the control is off the screen and then try to capture the image of the control.

Comment: capture the image? sorry I don't really understand the question.

Comment: By capture I mean get the bitmap of the control image.  If the control is obscured or off the screen, you will get garbage or black.  So, how for example would one go about getting a bitmap of the entire window to use for let's say printing. What I'm looking for is some sort of window that's 1) Not displayed 2) who's bits are always there 3) can have children.

Comment: a hidden window? your question is really unclear.

Comment: @vulkanino:  all I care about is that it has the 3 properties I listed. 1) It does not appear on the display 2) all the bits in it's window size are always available 3) it has a HWND and can have children.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8644/discussion-between-mike-d-and-vulkanino)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the simple answer to my question is NO!

Answer (score -1):

You have to process `WM_PAINT` and draw the image there.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hDC, memDc;
    PAINTSTRUCT Ps;
    HBITMAP bmpBackground;
    BITMAP bm;

    switch (message)                   
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;

        case WM_PAINT:
            hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &Ps);

            // Load the bitmap from the resource
            bmpBackground = LoadBitmap(hInst, "your_background_image");
            // Create a memory device compatible with the above DC variable
            memDc = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
            // Select the new bitmap
            SelectObject(memDc, bmpBackground);

            GetObject(bmpBackground, sizeof(bm), &bm);
            // Copy the bits from the memory DC into the current dc
            BitBlt(hDC, 10, 10,bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, memDc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            // Restore the old bitmap
            DeleteDC(memDc);
            DeleteObject(bmpBackground);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &Ps);
            break;

        default:                    
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is about drawing to a bitmap-backed window, not drawing a bitmap to a window.